# How to add two figures side by side, and insert captions to each of them?

Tags: ms-word, figure, caption

In Word, I can add two figures side by side, however, when I insert captions to each of them, the figure number doesn't change, both of them have the same figure number. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can put the figures into a borderless two-column table. Your pictures are actually put in an invisible table. Then you can add captions to each of the pictures and Word will provide different figure numbers.